# Ajax commenting solution

Tags: channel-entries, ajax, comments, dynamic, comment-form

Has anyone successfully wrote any scripts for ajax commenting in expression engine? I can't find any documentation that supports it for this style of commenting. Ellis Lab seem to have documentation for AJAX editing comments. Below you can see my basic tags. Any Ideas guys?

```
{exp:comment:form channel="thischannel" entry_id="{entry_id}" dynamic="no" }
                                                                        <form id="review_submit">
                                                                        <div id="name_it">
                                                                            <label>Name</label>
                                                                            <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" placeholder="myname"/>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="review_text">
                                                                    <label>Review</label>
                                                                    <textarea id="mycomment" name="comment" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea> 
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" class="back_button" id="tryme">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </form>
                                                            {/exp:comment:form}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do all of my AJAX form submissions with the jquery ajax form plugin. This allows you to customize the experience for your users here is the link to the plugin its very simple to implement.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Hope this helps!